# Azure RM Powershell find a particular file in all Resource Groups or App Services

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-rm

**Background**

Currently we are trying to trace the environment of a particular static site. (URL, Repo, Resource Group, etc.)

**Question**

Is there an existing cmdlet or aparticular way 
to find a particular file in all our available Resource Groups or App Services? 
For example, in all resource groups, find `particularfile.html`

**What we've tried**

We first tried to identify the location of our file by trying to identify  [here](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip131.html)

At first we tried to identify  all urls of all our sites by running the following command : `Get-AzureRmWebApp | foreach-object {$_} | select-object SiteName, DefaultHostName, ResourceGroup`

While we were able to get the urls, we realized that some redirected to different urls and was thus inaccurate. We still can't tell which resource group has our site..

so we are trying the approach where we look for the file itself. We know that `particularfile.html` itself exists in one of the resource groups or App Services.

Is there a command for it? or another approach to get the exact location of that file?

Comment: I really doubt that

Comment: hi @4c74356b41 thanks for the response... would you have any other advice as to how we can trace said file from our Resource Groups/app services??

Comment: You mean the file is in your web app? It can be found in the kudu console?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to look around, and see the various directories and files in your deployment, you can enter the site's "Kudu" dashboard, using the url format http://.scm.azurewebsites.net

This will give you a web-based dashboard, including a debug console (web-based) where you can explore your various directories (and the directories will show up visually as well).

you can check [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about/) for further information.

Comment: Right, but the problem is we currently have a lot (a LOT) of Resource Groups and App Services. Is there a much more ideal way of locating a particular file among them rather than accessing them one by one on the Kudu dashboard?